# Edittext background as straight line

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to make the edittext background just a straight line instead of usual. I used custom drawable shape for that. But the line is getting added in the middle of the edittext instead of bottom as the regular edittext line. Also when I press enter, it doesn't remain below the cursor as it should be. Is there any good way to do this?

Custom Drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="line">

    <stroke 
        android:color="#FA58AC"
        android:width="1dp"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: kishore code is right but if you want to show the background of the edittext transparent use this <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"

                android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think It will be helpful for you.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            // Your line color
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            // Your background color
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/color_black_light"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/color_black_light"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/edittext_line_color" />
```

Comment: Please don't just code dump, add some background information on what you have done and how this resolves the OPs issue